# How do I pull across checkbox data from one table to another in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm using a timesheet template from access and I need to modify it a bit. I have two tables.  Accounts and Work Hours.  On the Accounts table is a list of all of our accounts with a billable checkbox.  There is also a pre built form which users input new records into the work hours table that includes the account they worked and the date.  The problem I'm having is that some days the account is billable, other days it's not.  I would like to turn the billable checkbox on the accounts table into an on/off switch for that account so that our admins can control when an account is billable and when it is not. So that when a user adds a new record into the work hours table either directly or with the form, the corresponding checkbox in the work hours table will already be yes/no and I can query those results after.  Anyone have any idea's?  It might be possible to do it with the form as well but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Accounts can provide the norm but you want to allow users to deviate. Allowing multiple users to change the value in Accounts will cause conflict when they are creating records for same account simultaneously. You need a yes/no field in WorkHours to indicate if specific record is billable and user will have to edit.

Comment: What exactly determines when account is billable? Why on 'some days' and not others? Code can set DefaultValue of checkbox on form.

Comment: I'm using the work hours table to tally another column called PC in a query.  We pay commission on some PC but not others and it depends on which day the PC was entered into the table and which account the PC falls under so that the output on the query will only sum the total of PC if billable is true.  I can do that right now with just a standard checkbox column on the work hours table, but I wanted to make it easier for everyone and give the admins a little more control as to when PC is payable and when it's not.

Comment: Please read [ask] and related help topics and improve your question (e-g add paragraphs). Most important on database development is data-structure and normalization, search for them! You shouldn't have a checkbox in the hours-table. Instead have flag if the hours are billed or not (invoice table?) and then query for that flag.

Comment: So you need to define the criteria for billable and then query for them (you know the day and the account. If you know what account are billable (at what days) , compute that.

Comment: Need rules for criteria to calculate. What are the criteria? Will likely need an IIf().  Or flag each record. Edit question to show sample data and desired output and attempted query.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by using an afterupdate event in the form i'm using to add data to the table. Afterupdate event is tied to the work code field and runs a dlookup when the field is selected on the form.

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

Me.BILLABLE = DLookup("BILLABLE", "Accounts", "ID =" & Me.[Work Code]) 

End Sub
```

Thank you everyone.